# Best way to select test sample size for huge test data set

Tags: testing, optimization, random, automation, sampling

I am writing an automation test case for lease time validation for dhcp subscribers.the total number of subscribers will vary from range 1000 to 10000.The logic is introducing some sleep inbetween and checking the value of lease timer and configured lease time is less.So this logic can not be applied for all subscriber count.I want to randomly select n of subscribers from total subscriber count.

Please can any one suggest me the simple yet best way to select test sample size(n) which will give best coverage of test samples .Since the verification logic is more complex the test data selection process should be simple in order to improve the test execution time

Comment: What do you mean by "which will cover all range" ?

Comment: What is "huge" in 1000 subscribers ? Will testing on 1000 subscribers take more than a millisecond ?

Comment: Yes.I cant run the test logic for all 1000 subscribers

Comment: I can't make sense of your question.

Comment: What about using `np.choice` to select a sample? For the rest, what you want it is very unclear to me (and it looks like I am not the only one). Please clarify your question.